# Probability of choosing an edge twice in a tetrahedron

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

The problem that I solved is: given a tetrahedron (see below figure for reference), for each face, you choose 1 of its 3 edges at random. What is the probability that an edge is picked twice?

The way I approached this problem is as follows:

I started with the bottom face (the one you can't see in the figure below). The probability of choosing a unique edge is 1. Then without loss of generality, say that we choose the edge shared with the dark green face so now the dark green face has a 2/3 probability of choosing a unique face. Again, without loss of generality, I said it chose the face shared with the brown face. 
So far, we have 1*2/3 as the probability for choosing unique edges for the first 2 faces. Now for the brown face, it could either choose the edge shared with the bottom face with probability 1/3 or it could choose the face with probability 1/3 with the lighter green face.

If it chooses the edge shared with the bottom face, then the lighter green face has a probability of 1 of choosing a unique edge. If it chooses the edge shared with the lighter green face, then the lighter green face has a probability of 2/3 of choosing a unique edge
so the probability of all 4 faces choosing a unique edge is

$$
1*\frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{3}(\frac{2}{3} + 1)  = \frac{10}{27}
$$
The probability of choosing an edge twice is thus the complement of this. I believe this is the correct answer, but I am having a hard time writing it out formally. By formally, I mean in terms of variables/events and in terms of total/conditional probabilities. The numbers that I wrote above are just things that made sense to me intuitively, but there's obviously no formality behind it.

How would you wrote this out formally?

I tried to define events $U1, U2, U3$ and  $U4$ as the events that face 1, face 2, face 3, and face 4 choose a unique edge, respectively. So the probability of all 4 faces choosing a unique edge is $P(U1, U2, U3, U4)$.

Then I tried to write this as
$$
P(U1, U2, U3, U4) = P(U1)P(U2|U1)P(U3|U1,U2) P(U4|U1, U2, U3)
$$

But it's not clear to compute these probabilities. I think $P(U1) = 1$ for the same reason I stated in my above solution (since it's the first face that picks an edge, all 3 of its edges have obviously never been picked before). Now, $P(U2|U1)$ is the probability that the second face chooses a unique edge given that the first edge is unique. $U1$ eliminates 1 possible edge to choose from for face 2, so we have $\frac{2}{3}$. But I'm kind of confused on how to compute $P(U3|U1,U2)$ and $P(U4|U1, U2, U3)$. It seems to compute $P(U3|U1,U2)$, we should apply the law of total probability and condition on another event, in this case, I think it should be conditioned on which face we choose. But I am lost here on how to write this out formally, and was hoping someone can assist.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation and explanation thereof are correct and clear; what you have there is good. I am not a fan of unnecessary formalism, and in all honesty I wouldn’t try for anything more formulaic; if you absolutely need such a write-up, I hope that someone will provide one.

At most I might have taken a different approach from the start, reducing it to a purely combinatorial problem. Since there are $4$ faces, each of which has $3$ edges, there are $3^4$ equiprobable ways to choose our $4$ edges. If $e$ is one of the edges, exactly $9$ of these ways involve choosing $e$: we must choose $e$ for each of the two faces adjacent to it, and we have $3^2=9$ choices of edges from the other two faces. Since there are $6$ edges, at first sight this means that there are $6\cdot9=54$ ways to choose an edge twice. However, this counts a few possibilities twice: for each edge $e$ there is exactly one edge $e'$ that does not share a face (or even a vertex) with $e$, and it is possible to choose both $e$ and $e'$. There are just $3$ such pairs of ‘opposite’ edges, so we’ve overcounted by $3$, and there are really only $54-3=51$ different ways to choose some edge twice. The probability of doing so is therefore $\frac{51}{81}=\frac{17}{27}$.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative approach. I like it. I was actually originally trying to approach it using combinatorics, but couldn't figure it out. This is just a brain teaser that I did, and I don't have to write it up, but I find myself frequently able to solve a probability problem, but not able to write it out formally. Sometimes, I'll unknowingly use conditional expectation and the law of total expectation without realizing it, so I've been trying to improve on that.

Comment: @David: You’re welcome. I’m more comfortable with combinatorics than with probability, so I tend to see combinatorial solutions first.